# JS function to validate for null input fields not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my JS.
All I need is function `validateForm` to check for empty fields on form with `id` `formId`
I never get the alert on browser.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.validateForm = validateForm;
        function validateForm(formId){
        var form=document.getElementById('#formId');
        for(i=0; i<form.childNodes.length; i++)
            if(form.childNodes[i].tagName!='INPUT'||
               typeof form.childNodes[i].value=="undefined")
                continue;
            else{
                var x=form.childNodes[i].value;
                if(x==null||x==""){
                    alert("please fill out all fields");
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
 </script>
```

Here is html:

```
  <form id="formId" name="myForm" action="mailto:" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  first field: <input type="text" name="first"></br>
  second field: <input type="text" name="second"></br>
  third field: <input type="text" name="third"></br>
  fourth field: <input type="text" name="fourth"></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I never get the alert on browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle to see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/p9pDu/1/

There are four changes needed in your code

1. Change the form's definition like this

   ```
   <form id="formId" name="myForm" action="mailto:" method="post">
   ```
2. Your `validateForm` function doesn't need any parameter.
3. When you use `document.getElementById` don't use `#`. So, it should be

   ```
   document.getElementById('formId')
   ```
4. You just need this line to make sure that `validateForm` is called when the form is submitted.

   ```
   $('#formId').on('submit', validateForm);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`validateForm` function is defined inside the document ready callback (in the callback function scope). This won't be accessible globally. But you are trying to access the function in your onsubmit event.

Do this just after function definition in the callback function to make the function available globally:

```
window.validateForm = validateForm;
```